# Testing app locally when using Esri-Leaflet ReverseGeoCoding method with ArcGIS Developers API key

Tags: arcgis-online-basemaps, reverse-geocoding, esri-leaflet, geocoding-service

While testing my app like so:

```
    esriLeafletGeocoder
      .reverseGeocode({
        apikey: process.env.ESRI_API_KEY,
      })
      .latlng([48.8583, 2.2945])
      .run(function (error, results, response) {
        if (error) {
          console.log("error", error);
          return;
        }

        console.log("results, response ", results, response);
      });
```

I suddenly began receiving the following error:

`error {code: 403, subcode: 2, message: "User does not have permissions to access 'world.geocodeserver'.", details: Array(0)}`

Which led me to check ArcGIS Developers developers website, I'm on the free free tier, but what if you are testing something with the same `lat/lng`?

Is there a best practice I should be following to cache this result so I don't get rate limited?

Comment: I am using https://developers.arcgis.com/

Comment: In my situation, I have a collection of objects which have lat and lng data, and I'm mapping over each one, thus kicking off a reverseGeocode call for each.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/73354711/820534